# bookstore-blazor-efcore demo solution

Tags: abp

I'm new to abp framework and I'm trying to start bookstore-blazor-efcore demo solution but I get this error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
> :44399/.well-known/openid-configuration:1

It seems to be related to identityserver.

Next error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
> :44399/api/abp/api-definition:1

Thanks in advance.

Michele

Comment: Is **Acme.BookStore.HttpApi.Host** running? The host project should be running can you check it is running or not?

Comment: Hi Veske, I noticed that solution was not set multiple startup project. problem is solved, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. You can close the question since your problem is resolved.